# iPhone Screen Rotation: Can I enforce 90 degree rotations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, screen, rotation

My iPhone app rotates fine in the simulator but when I deploy it on a physical device, rotating is very very sensitive. How can I fix this issue and make sure the screen rotates only when a 90 degree angle is made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend manually monitoring the accelerometer for the angles you want to rotate at, then forcing your view controller to rotate to that orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you couldn't use the built-in autorotate callbacks for your requirements but have to build your own view rotation or alternate views that are controlled by readings from the accelerometer.

Comment: i am using the autorotate callbacks at the moment, and the phone does rotate, however if i slightly tilt it, it will go back into portrait mode. any way I can decrease/fix the sensitivity at least?